# how to distinguish between multiple jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, jasmine

I have a group of tests that have knockout validation that will call an email checker before calling the api I wish to test.

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('/api/register/').andReturn({
    'status': 201,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'responseText': '{"result":"ok"}',
});
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('/api/email-ok/?email=test%40example.com').andReturn({
    'status': 200,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'responseText': 'true',
});
var u = new User();
u.registrationEmail('test@example.com');
var d = u.register('/api/register/');
d.then(() => {
    var request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
....
```

Here the mostRecent() may be the email-ok api rather than the register api which I want to check.  How do I distinguish between the two mock calls using jasmine.Ajax so i can check the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function to enumerate the requests and pick one by URL.  Based upon this gist: [log all jasmine requests](https://gist.github.com/luqmaan/05e4671079622da21a8f) As follows:

```
function getRequestForUrl(url) {

    for (var i = 0; i < jasmine.Ajax.requests.count(); i++) {
        var req = jasmine.Ajax.requests.at(i);
        if(url == req.url){
            return req;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```